# How to renew DHCP lease via cron job?

Tags: network, cron

I have a machine that reboots nightly, but when it does it ends up connecting to the wrong router somehow, and always gets the wrong IP.  I don't want it to use a static IP, I have my router issue it a reserved address.

Anyway, it's easily fixed by renewing the DHCP lease (Ethernet, not wifi), but I want this to be automated after the reboot.  I can't get this to work from cron for some reason... I've tried both of these:

```
* * * * * echo "add State:/Network/Interface/en0/RefreshConfiguration temporary" | sudo scutil
* * * * * sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

Neither does anything from Cron, but works fine from the CLI manually.

How can I get this to work via cron?

EDIT: I have tried using the root user as suggested in the first answer, but this also does nothing.  No change, nothing output to a log, just nothing.

Comment: Why sudo, and where should the password come from when run from cron?

Comment: I just used code snippets I found on articles explaining how to renew the IP from cron.  I just used them as-is, though I assumed sudo would be needed since it's going to run unmonitored, but maybe not?  I'll try without it, though I run a nightly shutdown command with sudo and no password so, I thought it would just work.

Comment: @nohillside no change without sudo.

Comment: Perhaps only one router should be serving DHCP? What's your network topology? How many networks, devices, etc?

Comment: DHCP is completely disabled on all but my primary router, the cable modem.  In particular, the router (Access Point actually) that this computer keeps connecting to, is absolutely positively set to DHCP disabled because it says so very clearly.  Netgear Nighthawk in AP mode.  This is the only computer exhibiting this issue, I have no real idea how it can be connecting to a router that is not issuing IP addresses.  It's a very odd problem.

Comment: If you run this cron job as your standard user, it won't have the necessary access rights. Either install the crontab for `root` or use an appropriate LaunchDaemon.

Comment: I'm already doing sudo crontab -e and running my shutdown from there with sudo, no problems.  Is that not the admin's Crontab?

Answer (score 1):

**Important first step**

Make sure `cron` is working. You need to grant `/usr/sbin/cron` full disk access. Here's a good [guide](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/). You should be able to have the current date and time appear in a file

```
* * * * * /bin/date > /Users/yourusername/cronout.txt
```

**Root crontab**

Adding `sudo` to a `crontab` entry won't work because `sudo` is requires you to enter your password when the the command runs and `cron` is not interactive so you cannot enter your password.

There are several ways to make this work. The easiest, and reasonable one for this use case, is to have this job run as root. Log in as root and create the `crontab` there.

```
% sudo -i # Opens an interactive shell as root 
root# EDITOR=nano crontab -e # EDITOR is probably not configured for root
```

That'll open the `nano` editor. Feel free to use `vi`. In the editor add one of your commands, without the `sudo`

```
* * * * * ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

Save. I like to test my `cron` entries with `crontab -l`. Once that's done, exit the shell logged in as root with `exit` or `^D`.

If you need to troubleshoot this problem further, add some logging information to `cron`. Change the line to

```
* * * * * ipconfig set en0 DHCP &>> /Users/JVC/cron.log
```

That will append the output of `cron` to a log file that you can read and discover why the command didn't work.

An alternate means to this end would be to modify your `sudoers` file via `visudo` to permit this command to run without requiring a password [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt).

That leaves open the questions of why 1) you need to reboot every night and 2) why this machine connects to the wrong router, but this should solve you immediate problem.

Comment: Hmmm ok this is slightly over my head at the moment but I'm sure I can figure it out.  I reboot nightly just because when I don't, I find the machine bogs down over time.  It's a dedicated media server running a variety of stuff like Plex, Sonarr, etc. and there seem to be memory leaks, so a nightly reboot keeps everything humming perfectly.  But this router thing is new and I have no idea why it happens.  Thanks, will see if I can get this to work.

Comment: One question.  Why does this need to run as root, when `sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now` runs just fine from my normal admin user?

Comment: OK I got it going, but it still does nothing.  The IP lease is never renewed.  I tried both code snippets I listed in my OP, neither does anything when run via crontab by the root user.  Also no log file is created when I add that.

Comment: @JVC when you issue the command with `sudo`, you are running whatever follows as root.

Comment: Right, which is exactly why I don't understand why I would need to actually log in as root in order to set this up.  I'm already running the command as root, but it doesn't work.  Only now I've confirmed that it doesn't work as the root user either.

Comment: The trouble I have with your statement about sudo not working, is that it DOES work for me, right now.  I've had sudo in my shutdown command for years, and it executes dutifully without any problem.  At the moment I've given up on this whole thing and just given the machine a static IP. I prefer not to do that but this machine never travels or connects to any other network so, easier than mucking about with all this nonsensical automation.  Thanks for your effort though, may it help someone else down the road.